# How to delete a row from the table Laravel in controller (does not contain id in databas)

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, orm

The database was not created by Laravel, but I want to delete a row from the table, and there is no "id" for this row, because it is an intermediate table, how in this case can I delete this row from the table ?!

```
$productCustomer->delete();
```

Tables it contains 3 columns:

- customer_id
- product_id
- date_added

Answer (score 2):

Make one column primary key in you model ProductCustomer.php

```
protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';
```

```
ProductCustomer::where('customer_id', $id)->delete();
```

But here Be sure that which row you need to delete
Because it delete more than one row if it matches. So you should take another where

```
ProductCustomer::where('customer_id', $customer_id)->where('product_id',$product_id)->delete();
```

Or you can add a new migration file where you add id column with auto increment

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete like without a primary key, you can set one.

Or use classical query (for example) :

```
ProductCustomer::where('customer_id', $id)->delete();
```